# Negative number of reviews pending approval

Tags: bug

I just had the pending edits bubble tell me that there was "-1" pending. This happened as I was accepting multiple edits with out refreshing the page. The other bubble on the page (which I didn't grab a screen shot of) was showing "0" correctly.

[image]

I am using Chrome 19.0.1084.52

Comment: Or maybe I am just so awesome that I was able to approve an edit that hadn't even happened yet.

Comment: [The same issue was raised on the global meta for the Stack Exchange network](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133602/should-it-be-possible-to-have-a-negative-number-of-suggested-edits-in-the-queue).